# Cant get the message when passing null value, instead getting an Unhandled exception at runtime

Tags: c#, exception, throw

[Main Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7Jlg.png)

[Stack class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LJeR.png)

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dNBL.png)

```
private readonly List<object> _stack = new List<object>();

        public void Push(object obj)
        {

            if (obj != null)
            {
                _stack.Add(obj);
            }

            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Null value is passed");
            }
```

I need to get the "Null value is passed" exception but am getting an Unhandled exception.

Comment: Please add the `Push(obj)` caller.
It would be useful if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "...am getting an Unhandled exception"... nobody can help you if you don't provide the message and **stack trace** of that exception (and maybe its inner exceptions).

Comment: Please provide more details of the exception you are getting

Comment: Can't be in the posted code ... debug properly and it may be in some other part of your code

Comment: If you pass `null` to `obj` parameter, then it will throw an `InvalidOperationException` and if you'll not handle that exception, it will be unhandled exception.

Comment: `Unhandled exception at compilation` Exceptions don't occur at compilation. Do you mean at compile time, or runtime? Can you update your question to include a screenshot of the exception occurring?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is unhandled because you are not catching it. The underlying exception should still be your invalid operation exception. Try to add a try/catch block where your calling your `Push` method:

```
 try
 {
     Push(null);
 }
 catch (InvalidOperationException ioex)
 {
     MessageBox.Show(ioex.Message);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     // Unhandled exception
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
 }
```

Otherwise without more information it is  hard to tell.